# Adding nodes to a tree

Tags: tree, go

I'm working on a project in the Go programming language where I need a tree structure and the ability to add nodes (alot of them) to the tree. Each node is a struct like the following:

```
type Node struct {
    ip net.IP
    nodes []Node
    value int
}
```

The number of nodes each node can have is variable (between 1-4). An IP address (I'll searching for late) can be contained at the node, but most nodes will be nil for that element.

I can easily do this in other langues, but I need to find an efficient way of adding these nodes to a tree in Go.

Comment: What kind of tree? Where do you need to be most efficient; inserting, accessing, deleting?

Comment: Efficiency is most important for inserting. Type of tree is not too important, I just need to preserve the structure as stated above.

Comment: What would you do in other languages? How is Go different? I don't really understand you question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For example, with `nodes` as a slice of pointers to `Node`,

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "net"
)

type Node struct {
    value int
    ip    net.IP
    nodes []*Node
}

func main() {
    node1 := Node{value: 1}
    node2 := Node{value: 2}
    node3 := Node{value: 3}
    node4 := Node{value: 4}
    node1.nodes = append(node1.nodes, &node2, &node3)
    node2.nodes = append(node2.nodes, &node4)
    node3.nodes = append(node3.nodes, &node4)
    fmt.Printf("node1: %p %v\n", &node1, node1)
    fmt.Printf("node2: %p %v\n", &node2, node2)
    fmt.Printf("node3: %p %v\n", &node3, node3)
    fmt.Printf("node4: %p %v\n", &node4, node4)
}
```

Output:

```
node1: 0xc200069100 {1 [] [0xc200069180 0xc200069200]}
node2: 0xc200069180 {2 [] [0xc200069240]}
node3: 0xc200069200 {3 [] [0xc200069240]}
node4: 0xc200069240 {4 [] []}
```

[Slice types](http://golang.org/ref/spec#Slice_types)

[Appending to and copying slices](http://golang.org/ref/spec#Appending_and_copying_slices)

[SliceTricks](http://code.google.com/p/go-wiki/wiki/SliceTricks)

[Pointer types](http://golang.org/ref/spec#Pointer_types)